# Ordering a Union Query in MS Access SQL

Tags: ms-access, sorting, union

OK I have a particularly nasty union ordering problem so any help would be appreciated.

The scenario is this:

Member Table with the following records (actual data):

```
REI882
YUI987
POBO37
NUBS26
BTBU12
MZBY10
TYBW54
```

(These are listed in the order I want them back from my query.)

There are a number of business rules about the construction of these MemberIDs which I believe are unrelated to the sort. They're historic and set in stone. I'm stuck with them. They indicate seniority of the member.

The ordering is done from the last 4 characters in the ID, ascending. The first two characters of the ID are completely meaningless as far as the sort is concerned.

So the topmost possible record is ??A001 (most senior) and the lowest possible record is  ??ZZ99 (least senior).

When I query my member table the list I get back must display most senior at top... Obviously a standard sort does not work. This is what I have to date:

The first of these queries deals with sorting members whose ID only has 1 leading letter. The second deals with those with 2 leading letters.

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT Member.ID
    FROM Member
    WHERE (((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],4,1)))=-1)) **check the 4th character is a digit
    ORDER BY (Mid([Member.ID],3,1)), (Mid([Member.ID],4,1)), (Mid([Member.ID],5,1)), (Mid([Member.ID],6,1))
) t1

UNION

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Member.ID
    FROM Member
    WHERE (((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],4,1)))=0)) **check the 4th character is a letter
    ORDER BY (Mid([Member.ID],3,1)), (Mid([Member.ID],4,1)), (Mid([Member.ID],5,1)), (Mid([Member.ID],6,1))
) t2
```

But I get CRAZY results with the union! If I run each of the selects individually - no problem my funky (heavily reliant on some nasty string manipulation in access!) sort works exactly as I want it.

I understand this is pretty complicated but I hope I've explained it clearly and that someone is up for some kudos for figuring it out!!!

*edit: The result from my query is seemingly random:*

```
YUI987
MZBY10
NUBS26
BTBU12
REI882
POBO37
TYBW54
```

Comment: i Have a similar problem where i have another program constantly inserting times for when someone finishes doing something, anyway i formatted the datetime with .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm/ss tt") by accident if you'll notice there's a dash where a ':' is suppose to be, anyway now that i fixed it, when i go to sort it #!%$'s up because some of the fields are not in the correct format and i want to make it able to sort based on times

Comment: My Question is Almost Exactly the same as this question; I simply figured since i added a bounty i might as well give some more detail that makes the currently given answers insufficient

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` in a `SELECT` statement that `UNION` with another `SELECT` is not correct.

See **Specifying a conditional order** [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx#Case)

You can use this:

```
SELECT ID FROM(  
(SELECT Member.ID,1 AS T,Left([Member.ID],2) AS Part1, Right([Member.ID],4) AS Part2
  FROM Member
  WHERE (((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],3,1)))=-1)))    
UNION    
  (SELECT Member.ID,2 AS T,Left([Member.ID],3) AS Part1, Right([Member.ID],3) AS Part2
  FROM Member
  WHERE (((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],4,1)))=-1) and ((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],3,1)))=0)))     
UNION    
  (SELECT Member.ID,3 AS T,Left([Member.ID],4) AS Part1, Right([Member.ID],2) AS Part2
  FROM Member
  WHERE (((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],5,1)))=-1) and ((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],4,1)))=0)))     

ORDER BY T,Part1,Part2)
```

@Justin Kirk:  I don't know what is your problem exactly. But I hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the [RIGHT](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/right.php) function.

Something like

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    (
            SELECT  ID 
            FROM    (
                        SELECT Member.ID
                        FROM Member
                        WHERE (((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],4,1)))=-1)) **check the 4th character is a digit
                    ) t1
            UNION
            SELECT  ID 
            FROM    (
                        SELECT Member.ID
                        FROM Member
                        WHERE (((IsNumeric(Mid([Member.ID],4,1)))=0)) **check the 4th character is a letter
                    ) t2
        ) t3
ORDER BY RIGHT(ID,4)
```

Comment: Thanks... much cleaner sort... but it gives me exactly the same wrong  result as my original solution.
`YUI987

MZBY10

NUBS26

BTBU12

REI882

POBO37

TYBW54`

Comment: I tested this with 2 tables and using the order by AFTER the union has been created works. Is the ORDER BY you use here slightly watered down from the actual version?

Answer (score 0):

How about skipping the UNION?

```
SELECT members.ID
FROM members
ORDER BY Right([ID],3), Right(id,4)
```

Based on the new rules, this mess may work.

```
SELECT 
    Len(IIf([textId] Like "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Left([textid],2),
    IIf([textId] Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Left([textid],3),
    IIf([textId] Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]",Left([textid],4),"_")))) AS Ln, 

    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Left(textid,2),
    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Left(textid,3),
    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]",Left(textid,4),"_"))) AS Alpha, 

    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Val(Right(textid,4)),
    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Val(Right(textid,3)),
    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]",Val(Right(textid,2)),0))) AS Numbr, 

    table.textid
FROM table
ORDER BY 
    Len(IIf([textId] Like "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Left([textid],2),
    IIf([textId] Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Left([textid],3),
    IIf([textId] Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]",Left([textid],4),"_")))), 

    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Left(textid,2),
    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Left(textid,3),
    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]",Left(textid,4),"_"))), 

    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Val(Right(textid,4)),
    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]",Val(Right(textid,3)),
    IIf(textId Like "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]",Val(Right(textid,2)),0)))
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL!!!!! Oh so bloody simple... why is it that once I start down a complicated path I just can't find my way back!

Comment: This answer seems to have been unaccepted, it would be nice to know why for future reference.

Comment: Unfortunately it just doesn't work. I had left some sample data out of the original problem statement (still in keeping with the posted business rules). When I put real data into the app the sort was not working as expected. I have changed the design of my app so I don't need this sort anymore. If you're interested the sample data to sort is: AA0001;ZZ9999;AAA001;ZZZ999;AAAA01;ZZZZ99 - this is an ID in the correct order I would want back from any query. I suspect that I'd have to write a custom procedure to implement this sort.