# Sorting Access Data (date times in the wrong format)

Tags: c#, ms-access

**Problem:**

Some of the fields in my table have the wrong format for a date, they're formatted using the .ToString() Method in C# but i made a typo and entered it like this : **MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm/ss tt**

Now, if you look closely you see MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm  ----> '**/**' <--- ss

which is suppose to be a '**:**'

I then preceded to fix it in my c# code, (meaning some of the values are formatted: **MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt**)

The problem is, i'm trying to select values from the table in order of Date (which i can't just Sort by 'Datefieldnamehere') because some of the fields are in the wrong format with a '/'

---

**What i have Tried:**

Now, i figured since the time is always in the same spot (and that's what matters to me) i could just take the substring of the numbers in the time and order them; first for **AM** then for **PM**

I could Order By MID([ColumnName],11,2) , MID([ColumnName],14,2), MID([ColumnName],16,2) because every date regardless of the delimiter is always in the format M/dd/yyyy hh/mm/ss tt

So I Tried:

---

```
(
SELECT SN, StatusCode, Time, Mid(Time,14,2) + ':'+ Mid(Time,17,2) AS TTI
FROM OrderStatus
WHERE StatusCode = 'Finished' and Left(Time,10) = '4/20/2012'
AND Time LIKE '*AM'
ORDER BY Val(Mid([Time],11,2)) DESC
)
UNION ALL (
SELECT SN, StatusCode, Time, Mid(Time,14,2) + ':'+ Mid(Time,17,2) AS TTI
FROM OrderStatus
WHERE StatusCode = 'Finished' and Left(Time,10) = '4/20/2012'
AND Time LIKE '*PM'
ORDER BY Val(Mid([Time],11,2)) DESC
);
```

---

Just to see if that would Order it by hour but it doesn't it gives me this :
[image: Err]

As you can see it goes (in the hour field) 01 then 02 and then it goes back to 01... ?

Anyway there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411827/ordering-a-union-query-in-ms-access-sql) That i have put a bounty on, you will earn the bounty if you answer this question or that question, this would be useful to know for other scenarios as well

**Edit:**
The Question that i really want answered how to sort by a Substring of a string; sorry for the late edit i could of swore i changed this already, say i want to sort by a single digit of any string / date / anything i was wondering how i can do something like:
 Order By Val(Mid(ColumnName,StartPos,EndPos))

**Note:** That Order By gives completely wrong results.

Comment: Yes but not really..., there's 21000+ records, i can't simply call .replace because there's /'s in the date earlier dividing year month and day, and i can't replace values at an exact spot in the substring because some dates have 10/11/12 (an extra digit) in the month, and i suppose i could do a if(date.length == 22) and 21 and etc to accompany for that, but that really defeats the purpose of this question for future use. What i really want to know is how to sort by a substring of a string in an column if that's even possible..

Comment: That's a really good suggestion though i'll vote it up

Comment: I think its always better to fix the problem then finding a complicated way of doing the job without having to fix it. Since this would be a one time thing to do, you could use a temporary field for date and one for time to split the field in question in. Then a somple replace should be easy. (I see that it doesn't answer the question of sorting by a substring though..;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a table to test, however I want to give my idea.
I will use the Left, Mid and Right function together with CDate and CInt functions.
I will get the leftmost part of Time Field (16 bytes), add a ":00" for the seconds and the PM/AM designator. This string can be converted to a date using CDate.
Then I will get the seconds part and convert them to an integer.
Now the order by could be reached ordering for the first part (TTI) and then for the second part (TTS) without using an UNION.
But there is a problem, some dates contains a month with only 1 char, (es: 4 april vs 12 december)  luckily, we can use the IIF operator to select the right numbers for mid, right and left.

EDIT:

```
SELECT 
SN, StatusCode, Time, 
IIF(Len(Time) = 22, Left(Time,16) + ':00' + Right(Time,2), Left(Time,15) + ':00' + Right(Time,2)) AS TTI, 
IIF(Len(Time) = 22, Mid(Time, 18,2), Mid(Time, 17,2)) as TTS
FROM OrderStatus 
WHERE StatusCode = 'Finished' and Left(Time,10) = '4/20/2012' 
ORDER BY CDate(IIf(Len([Time])=22,Left([Time],16)+ ':00 ' + Right([Time],2),Left([Time],15)+ ':00 ' + Right([Time],2))) DESC , 
         CInt(IIf(Len([Time])=22,CInt(Mid([Time],18,2)),CInt(Mid([Time],17,2)))) DESC;
```

Comment: This is the wrong usage of left and right isn't it ? Left has 2 parameters not 3

Comment: is 'Length' interchangable with 'Val'? it doesn't recognize it

Comment: @JustinKirk, Oh well another error. The function is Len. Sorry, I'm working on a C# project and sometimes I tend to mix the two :)

Comment: Also you have 2 if statements and in both of them you put an 'as' clause and then at the end you sort by both of them ,... but only 1 of them can possibly exist

Comment: hmm... it worked kind of, it sorted by the outer seconds column, the TTI column was all '#Error's' I'm assuming that's because the if statement saw that it was 22 digits, i don't know anything about IIF, Anyway you can't sort by column name generated in 'as' statements, you have to put the query expression as the sort clause like : ORDER BY CInt(Mid(Time, 18,2)), CInt(Mid(Time, 17,2)), CDate(Left(Time,15) + ':00' + Right(Time,2)) DESC

Comment: This seems like overkill to sort by a single digit in a column... if nobody finds a better solution i'll select it

Comment: @JustinKirk It's really a bad situation. If constraints permits it's a way better to try to correct the situation with a global update

Comment: Yes, what if you don't have write access to the database ? and you need to sort a field in your select by a single digit; Wouldn't that leave you in a scenario where you couldn't correct the situation? Sorting by a single digit shouldn't be complicated at all, Infact i assumed Order By Val(Mid(ColumnName,x,y) would be sufficient; If you follow the link to the question i have a bounty on it gives another similar scenario

Comment: @JustinKirk I have managed to set up a table like yours and corrected something in the query (Len=22). But probably you have already figured out by yourself

Answer (score 3):

My instinct is to create a function and run it once in an Access UPDATE statement to convert the stored values to match the desired format.

The quick & dirty function below copes with both single and two digit months.  It requires Access 2000 or later.

```
? FixTimeData("4/20/2012 01:34/09 PM")
4/20/2012 01:34:09 PM
? FixTimeData("12/20/2012 01:34/09 PM")
12/20/2012 01:34:09 PM

Public Function FixTimeData(ByVal pIn As String) As String
    Dim astrPieces() As String
    Dim strOut As String
    astrPieces = Split(pIn, " ")
    strOut = astrPieces(0) & " " & _
        Replace(astrPieces(1), "/", ":") & " " & _
        astrPieces(2)
    FixTimeData = strOut
End Function
```

Then an UPDATE statement similar to this ...

```
UPDATE OrderStatus
SET time_field = FixTimeData(time_field)
WHERE time_field Like "*/*/*/*";
```

If you run the statement under ADO instead of DAO, change to ANSI wild card characters in the WHERE clause.

```
WHERE time_field Like "%/%/%/%";
```

Or use ANSI wild cards with ALike if you want the same statement to work under either ADO or DAO.

```
WHERE time_field ALike "%/%/%/%";
```

I used `time_field` as the field name where you used `Time` because `Time` is a reserved word.  If you can't change the field name, enclose it with square brackets in your query.

**Edit**: My intention was to fix the data so you can then sort reliably based on `Right(time_field, 11)`

**Edit2**: To sort based on the "upper" minute digit, see if you can build on this approach, which assumes you have fixed the stored date/time strings:

```
? Left(Format(Minute("4/23/2012 04:02:40 PM"), "00"), 1)
0
? Left(Format(Minute("4/23/2012 04:12:40 PM"), "00"), 1)
1
? Left(Format(Minute("4/23/2012 04:22:40 PM"), "00"), 1)
2
```

Although the `Minute()` function accepts a string, I would likely use `CDate()` to explicitly transform the string to a Date/Time before feeding it to `Minute()`.

So ... if I haven't gone completely astray ... try that approach in a query like this:

```
SELECT
    Left(Format(Minute(CDate(time_field)), "00"), 1) AS upper_minute,
    OrderStatus. *
FROM OrderStatus
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: This is a good fix for my problem(I can fix it quite similarly using c#), but it ignores the main point of the question; How can i Sort a table by a Substring of a column: All of my Google results suggest that i can Order By Left/Right/Mid(ColumnName, Length) or in Mid's case (ColumnName, Start, Length) but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: After you fix the data, doesn't `Right(time_field, 11)` give you the correct sort?

Comment: Yes it does !, but what if i try or find a need to sort by the Upper Minutes Column, hh: -->m<-- m:ss is it not possible to sort by that ?

Comment: i voted you're answer up, you're attention is/was much appreciated (>^_^)>

Answer (score 2):

Make date filed to be real date field instead of string. Migrate all values to new field with 2 updates - one that selects all rows with old format, another with new. Drop string column for date and enjoy properly typed data.

If you really want to keep it as string at least make sure to use standard ISO8601 format (approximately YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM.ssss) that is safe for sorting/localization.

Comment: there's 8000+ line of code not written by me accessing this data as a string in c#, i cannot simply change it to a date time or i would have already.

Comment: I voted your answer up as i appreciate your attention and you are very correct (it should be a real date, not a string) but it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Thanks. I'd still recommend switching to sortable string format if you end up touching this code anyway. HansUp's conversion looks exactly what you need.